# VBA Error 1004: Copy method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row, paste

I'm having a bit of trouble with any kind of paste method I use at the moment. I have to copy data from a sheet and paste it to another, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
Dim idSelect As Integer
Dim nRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rowNum As Integer

idSelect = Worksheets("dest").Range("C2").Value - 1
rowNum = 5

nRow = Worksheets("origin").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To nRow
    If Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 1).Value = "No" Then 'if do not ignore
    
        If idSelect > 0 And (Left(Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 6).Value, 1) Or Left(Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 7).Value, 1) = idSelect) Then

            Range(Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 3), Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 27)).Copy
            Worksheets("dest").Range(Cells(rowNum, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
            
        End If
    End If
    
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Change `Range(Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 3), Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 27)).Copy` to `Worksheets("origin").Range(Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 3), Worksheets("origin").Cells(i, 27)).Copy` and `Worksheets("dest").Range(Cells(rowNum, 1)).PasteSpecial` to `Worksheets("dest").Cells(rowNum, 1).PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` are all ranges. A range belongs to a worksheet and you need to tell VBA which worksheet it should use. If you don't tell, VBA assumes the `Activesheet`.

`Worksheets("dest").Range(Cells(rowNum, 1))` tells VBA you want to use a Range from worksheet `dest`. You then want to specify which part of the sheet you need by using `Cells(rowNum, 1))`. However you don't tell VBA from what worksheet you want `Cells`, and while it seems obvious for a human that you want the cells from worksheet `dest`, it's not. VBA will assume `Activesheet.Cells(rowNum, 1)`, and as that cell is not part of the worksheet `dest`, you get a runtime error.

So the correct way would be (*wait, don't use it*)

```
Worksheets("dest").Range(Worksheets("dest").Cells(rowNum, 1)).PasteSpecial
```

As this is a monster, there are shortcuts. Either use a `With`-Clause or assign the sheet to a variable (*wait, it still gets easier*)

```
' Either 
With Worksheets("dest")
    .Range(.Cells(rowNum, 1)).PasteSpecial
End With
' --- Or
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Set destSheet = Worksheets("dest")
destSheet.Range(destSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1)).PasteSpecial
```

Now, at the top I stated that `Cells` are Ranges. `Cells(rowNum, 1)` is a Range (containing one cell). You can simply use

```
 Worksheets("dest").Cells(rowNum, 1).PasteSpecial
' --- Or
With Worksheets("dest")
    .Cells(rowNum, 1).PasteSpecial
End With
' --- Or
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Set destSheet = Worksheets("dest")
destSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1).PasteSpecial
```

... and now the next thing you need to learn is that you need to tell VBA in which Workbook it should look for the `Worksheets` - else it assumes the `ActiveWorkbook`.